# Getting error that Firebase Firestore imports are not declared even if in import statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a document from Firebase Firestore but every time I try getting it I get an error that my "onHomeLoad" function is not declared and if I put it in the console I then get either that doc() or getDoc() aren't declared.
I tried everything I've found online but nothing worked.

My code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore , getDoc , doc } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-firestore.js";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
});

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

function onHomeLoad() {
    let siteSettingsHome = doc(db, 'siteSettings/home');
    getDocument(siteSettingsHome);
}
async function getDocument(docLocation) {
    let documentSnapshot = await getDoc(docLocation);
    if( homeSettingSnapshot.exists() ){
        let documentData = documentSnapshot.data();
        console.log(`Doc data: ${JSON.stringify( documentData )}`);
        return documentData;
    }
}
```

I've removed the stuff inside the initializeApp object here but it's filled correctly in my js document.

Comment: Not sure that we could use browser modules in node.js for importing (even with ESM) or could we do that ? Try installing modules like this `npm install firebase
` and and import like `import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';`.

Comment: I have installed them already and I've tried reinstalling them multiple times

Comment: Since you are installing the modules, how are you importing them , as mentioned in your question , if yes . Then import it like this `import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';` .

Comment: If I do it like this then it doesnt work at all, firefox says that modules must start with /, ./ or ../ and if i add them it doesnt work either

Comment: From the really small things i know i think i have to make a bundle.js but i don't know how